# Can't solve "Can't read property X of null" error

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have an index.html file that has

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="2-4.js"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

and a 2-4.js file that has

```
var div,
    container = document.getElementById('container')
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    div = document.createElement('div')
    div.onclick = function() {
        alert('This is box #' + i)
    }
container.appendChild('div')
}
```

They're in the same folder. When I open index.html in Chrome and inspect, I see "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null at 2-4.js:11" in the console. I looked up some SO questions involving that error but didn't find them helpful. Does anyone have an idea what's going on? Am I running the program wrong?

Comment: There is no element with an id of `container`. Did you mean to include this script within a different html file?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to do this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body><div id="container"></div></body>
<script>

var container = document.getElementById('container');
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.onclick = function() {
        alert('This is box #' + i);
    }
    container.appendChild(div);
}

</script>
</html>
```

Basically the message says that null (as in, no object ref) does not have a property or method 'appendChild', which is obvious, because document.getElementById('container') will return nothing, as it can't find such an element, simply because its not there...

Comment: You need to load the script at the end of the body or use `window.onload`.

Comment: @Barmar, its formatted just the way the OP showed - the javascript is in a seperate file

Comment: Putting it in a separate file doesn't help. You need to put the `<script>` that loads the file after the element that it tries to access. Otherwise `getElementById()` will return `null` because the element doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Or the script need to put the code that calls that into a `window.onload` function. Read the duplicate question for details.

Comment: You're right. too soon to answer :)